How to stop a call to map if nested find returns None?
I have the following struct:
struct Thing {
    id: usize,
    cost: u32,
    numbers: Vec<usize>
}

I am considering the following three Thing objects and a vector chain_of_things that contains some Ids:
let some_things = [
    Thing { id: 0, cost: 10, numbers: vec![1, 2] },
    Thing { id: 1, cost: 15, numbers: vec![3] },
    Thing { id: 2, cost: 20, numbers: vec![0, 1] },
    Thing { id: 3, cost: 5, numbers: vec![1] }
];
let chain_of_things = [0, 1, 3];

Note that for convenience, the Ids of the Things in the vector some_things coincide with their position in the vector. A pair (thing_1, thing_2) is feasible, if the id of thing_2 is contained in thing_1.numbers.
The task is to find out if the given chain_of_things is feasible, meaning that for every index i the pair (some_things[chain_of_things[i]], some_things[chain_of_things[i+1]]) must be feasible. If the chain is feasible, I want to return the sum of the costs of the things. Otherwise, I want to return an error.
Solving this task using a for loop is trivial. I want to solve it using a call to map and inside if a call to find. My approach so far looks as follows:
let mut cost = some_things[chain_of_things[0]].cost;

let results: Vec<_> =
    chain_of_things[..chain_of_things.len() - 1]
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(index, thing_id)| {
            if let Some(number) = some_things[*thing_id].numbers
                .iter()
                .find(|&&x| {x == chain_of_things[index + 1] })
            {
                cost += some_things[chain_of_things[index + 1]].cost;
                cost
            }
            else {
                u32::MAX
            }
        }).collect();

This works but has multiple drawbacks:

I need to iterate over the result vector to search for a MAX value to determine if all pairs were feasible.
The map iterator does not stop as soon as the first non-feasible pair is found.

How do I achieve a behavior that circumvents the mentioned drawbacks?
My question seems to be related to: How do I stop iteration and return an error when Iterator::map returns a Result::Err?
I think the solution there is to have an extra find function that returns a Result<T, E>. But the find function I'm calling returns an Option<T>. I could write my own find function but it would only wrap the Option<T> and somehow convert it into a Result<T, E> which seems overkill.

You can just replace Result<T, ()> with Option<T>  in any answer to that question you found as Option also implements FromIterator and Try.

IOW, just have your map closure return Some (…) for valid pairs and None for invalid pairs, then collect into an Option<Vec<_>>

This solution seems fairly idiomatic. You can add prints into map(|pair| ... line to verify that the chain is not processed further after encountering first bad pair.
let chain_of_things = [0,1,3];
let sum_cost = chain_of_things
    .map(|i| &some_things[i]) // get things by indices
    .windows(2) // iterate pairs in chain
    .map(|pair| pair[0].numbers
        .contains(&pair[1].id)
        .then_some(pair[1].cost)
    ) // get Some(cost) if feasible, else None
    .sum::<Option<u32>>() // Option implements Sum, stopping iteration on first None
    .map(|sum| sum + some_things[chain_of_things[0]].cost); // add first thing's cost

println!("Answer: {:?}", sum_cost);


I never realized Result and Option implement Sum this way, that's very useful to know and will reduce the number of places I reach for try_fold() to get this behavior!

@mattnewport If I understand the docs correctly, sum of Options ignores None, but iterates them until the iterator is exhausted, and sum of Result short-circuits on Err. Also sometimes it's useful that () implements .collect, to aggregate function calls that all return () or Result<(), Error>

It looks to me like Sum<Option>> also short circuits: "Takes each element in the Iterator: if it is a None, no further elements are taken, and the None is returned. Should no None occur, the sum of all elements is returned."

@mattnewport Hmm, excellent, I can simplify the snippet in my answer :)

You could just use map() rather than and_then() after sum() here and not need to wrap the result in Some().

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, then I think you want try_fold() rather than map().
Your aim as I understand it is to return the sum of costs if every pair in the chain is feasible and an error otherwise so the closure you pass to try_fold() should return None if an index is not feasible, otherwise Some(cost_running_total). You will end up with a single optional value which will early out with None if a non-feasible index is encountered, otherwise it will contain the sum if all items were feasible.
You could also simplify your code by using windows(2) to iterate over adjacent pairs of entries in chain_of_things.
Code would look something like this:
let result = chain_of_things
    .windows(2)
    .map(|ids| (&some_things[ids[0]], &some_things[ids[1]]))
    .try_fold(
        some_things[chain_of_things[0]].cost,
        |acc, (thing1, thing2)| {
            thing1
                .numbers
                .contains(&thing2.id)
                .then_some(acc + thing2.cost)
        },
    );

match result {
    Some(cost) => println!("Total feasible cost: {cost}"),
    None => println!("Not feasible"),
}

